# converting large numerical value to power 10 format

Tags: numbers, integer, sas

Is there a way to convert large numerical value to *10 to the power format in sas?

Eg: 88888888383383838383 to 8.8*10^6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear: you're talking about how it's formatted on the screen, not any sort of rounding or truncation, correct?  IE, you don't mind that it's still the underlying precise (mostly) value if you were to do math on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format `ew.` where the w the number output characters.  Using `e8.` will result in `8.9E+19`.  But beware that SAS uses floating point to store values internally, with a maximum of 8 bytes.  Your example value would be rounded to 88,888,888,383,383,830,528 (no matter how it's formatted).

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I will try that one.